# Value from value-of element not being output in XML to CSV map

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, schema

I am trying to understand how XPath works in my case. My problem is simple. I want to output the `VATIdentificationNumber` of the applicant to the `VATIdentificationNumber` element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0" version="1.0" xmlns:ns0="http://customerNamespace" xmlns:s0="http://inputNamespace">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:CDM_VATRefundApplication" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:CDM_VATRefundApplication">
    <ns0:VatRefund>
      <GeneralData>
        <LineCode>01</LineCode>
        <VATIdentificationNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="Applicant/VATIdentificationNumber"></xsl:value-of>
        </VATIdentificationNumber>
      </GeneralData>
    </ns0:VatRefund>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My input schema is structured as so:

[image]

From what I understand with how scope works in XSLT, I am currently on my root node, since the template matches `/`. As such I should be able to select the `Applicant` element which is a child of the root node. When I test the code I get the `VATIdentificationNumber` element output, but with no value.

What is the correct XPath to use in this case? I've tried adding the namespace, use the full path, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you show your actual XML rather than an image of the structure. My guess would be that `Applicant` and `VATIdentificationNumber` are both in the same namespace as `CDM_VATRefundApplication` too, and so should be prefixed with `s0` in your XSLT too. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, prefixing both the fields solved it!